# ROS Eloquent - Gazebo10 integration

Tags: gazebo, ros2, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am failing to integrate a ROS node with a Gazebo10 plugin. I am following this tutorial more or less but translating to the ROS2 API: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i6 . It seems that there is something wrong in my declaration of a subscription. I can't upload my file because I don't have 5 points, but I have copied the relevant code. I do not want to use gazebo_ros_pkgs.

```
    // Initialize ros, if it has not already been initialized
    if (!rclcpp::is_initialized())
    {
      int argc = 0;
      char** argv = NULL;
      //rclcpp::init(argc, argv, rclcpp::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
      rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    }

    // Setup callback group
    this->rosCallbackGroup = this->rosNode->create_callback_group(
        rclcpp::callback_group::CallbackGroupType::MutuallyExclusive);

    // Setup subscriber options
    this->rosSubOptions = rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions();
    this->rosSubOptions.callback_group = this->rosCallbackGroup;

    // Setup subscriber
    this->rosSub = this->rosNode->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::Float32>(
        "/" + this->model->GetName() + "/vel_cmd",
        rclcpp::QoS(1),
        boost::bind(&VelodynePlugin::OnRosMsg, this, _1),
        this->rosSubOptions);
```

Generating the following error:

```
In file included from /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/client.hpp:31:0,
                 from /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/callback_group.hpp:23,
                 from /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/any_executable.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/memory_strategy.hpp:24,
                 from /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/memory_strategies.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/executor.hpp:33,
                 from /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/executors.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:145,
                 from /ros2-dev/gazebo/.gazebo/plugins/velodyne/velodyne_plugin.cc:8: /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/function_traits.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct rclcpp::function_traits::function_traits<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, gazebo::VelodynePlugin, std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::Float32_<std::allocator<void>
> > >, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<gazebo::VelodynePlugin*>, boost::arg<1> > > >’: /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/subscription_traits.hpp:90:8: required from ‘struct rclcpp::subscription_traits::has_message_type<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, gazebo::VelodynePlugin, std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::Float32_<std::allocator<void>
> > >, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<gazebo::VelodynePlugin*>, boost::arg<1> > >, void, void, void>’ /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/node.hpp:199:5: required by substitution of ‘template<class MessageT, class CallbackT, class AllocatorT, class CallbackMessageT, class SubscriptionT, class MessageMemoryStrategyT> std::shared_ptr<SubscriptionT> rclcpp::Node::create_subscription(const string&, const rclcpp::QoS&, CallbackT&&, const rclcpp::SubscriptionOptionsWithAllocator<AllocatorT>&, typename MessageMemoryStrategyT::SharedPtr) [with MessageT = std_msgs::msg::Float32_<std::allocator<void>
>; CallbackT = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, gazebo::VelodynePlugin, std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::Float32_<std::allocator<void>
> > >, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<gazebo::VelodynePlugin*>, boost::arg<1> > >; AllocatorT = std::allocator<void>; CallbackMessageT
= <missing>; SubscriptionT = <missing>; MessageMemoryStrategyT = <missing>]’ /ros2-dev/gazebo/.gazebo/plugins/velodyne/velodyne_plugin.cc:128:32: required from here /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/function_traits.hpp:52:82: error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function
     typename function_traits<decltype( &FunctionT::operator())>::arguments>::type;
                                                                                  ^ /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/function_traits.hpp:57:72: error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function    using argument_type = typename std::tuple_element<N, arguments>::type;
                                                                        ^ /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/function_traits.hpp:59:95: error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function    using return_type = typename function_traits<decltype( &FunctionT::operator())>::return_type;
                                                                                               ^ /ros2-dev/gazebo/.gazebo/plugins/velodyne/velodyne_plugin.cc: In member function ‘void gazebo::VelodynePlugin::ExecutorThread()’: /ros2-dev/gazebo/.gazebo/plugins/velodyne/velodyne_plugin.cc:128:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘rclcpp::Node::create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::Float32>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, rclcpp::QoS, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, gazebo::VelodynePlugin, std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::Float32_<std::allocator<void>
> > >, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<gazebo::VelodynePlugin*>, boost::arg<1> > >, rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions&)’
             this->rosSubOptions);
                                ^ In file included from /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/executors/single_threaded_executor.hpp:28:0,
                 from /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/executors.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:145,
                 from /ros2-dev/gazebo/.gazebo/plugins/velodyne/velodyne_plugin.cc:8: /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/node.hpp:208:3: note: candidate: template<class MessageT, class CallbackT, class AllocatorT, class CallbackMessageT, class SubscriptionT, class MessageMemoryStrategyT> std::shared_ptr<SubscriptionT> rclcpp::Node::create_subscription(const string&, const rclcpp::QoS&, CallbackT&&, const rclcpp::SubscriptionOptionsWithAllocator<AllocatorT>&, typename MessageMemoryStrategyT::SharedPtr)    create_subscription(    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/eloquent/include/rclcpp/node.hpp:208:3: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/velodyne_plugin.dir/velodyne_plugin.cc.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/velodyne_plugin.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Edit: Compilation solved. Switch `boost::bind()` to `std::bind()` (#include ) && switch `_1` to `std::placeholders::_1`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342600/ros-eloquent---gazebo10-integration/) by [errcsool](https://answers.ros.org/users/51260/errcsool/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-27**:
I would recommend you edit your question and include a verbatim copy of the error message, then format it with the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it). As-is, the error message is almost unreadable.

**Comment by [errcsool](https://answers.ros.org/users/51260/errcsool/) on 2020-01-27**:
Could you give me the points to upload a file? It would be much simpler

**Comment by [errcsool](https://answers.ros.org/users/51260/errcsool/) on 2020-01-27**:
Edit: My function declaration OnRosMsg(const std_msgs::msg::Float32::SharedPtr) is correct. Switching from boost::bind to std::bind generates a different long error

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-27**:\

> Could you give me the points to upload a file? It would be much simpler

there is no support to upload text files or source code. So giving you points would not seem to help.

If you intended to upload a screenshot then I would point you to the [Support Guidelines](https://wiki.ros.org/Support) which explicitly state you should not do that.

**Comment by [errcsool](https://answers.ros.org/users/51260/errcsool/) on 2020-01-27**:
I intend to use the `attachment` (paperclip) function on the edit bar

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-27**:
That only allows image type attachments. Not sure whether that is because of configuration or just how Askbot works.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-27**:
Please post your last edit as an answer and accept your own answer.

**Comment by [errcsool](https://answers.ros.org/users/51260/errcsool/) on 2020-01-27**:
I can't accept my own answer, as I need >10 points.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-28**:
I've accepted it for you.

Thanks for reporting your solution and for posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Compilation solved. Switch boost::bind() to std::bind() (#include ) && switch _1 to std::placeholders::_1

---

Originally posted by [errcsool](https://answers.ros.org/users/51260/errcsool/) with karma: 26 on 2020-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-28**:
It would be even nicer if you could include a short code-snippet that shows the exact syntax. Future readers may not be able to translate your answer into code themselves.